# Column LOOKUP Dynamic Query (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Trying 'query' for the first time in google sheets. Need some assistance. Thanks in advance.**

I have a google sheet with two tabs "sheet 1" and "sheet 2"

**Sheet 1 Structure:**

[image]

**Sheet 2 Structure:**

[image]

I am trying to create a dynamic query, where if Entity = Person "x"  and Value  = A or B or C, the Des number (from sheet2) is populated in Sheet 1 in yellow cells

So far I have tried these queries and for some reason it throws a "#N/A" error

1. QUERY({Sheet2!$A$1:$AC$10}, "SELECT Col1,Col"&MATCH(B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$AC$1,0))
2. LOOKUP($B$1,QUERY({Sheet2!$A$1:$AC$10}, "SELECT Col1, Col"&MATCH("L",Sheet2!$A$1:$AC$1,0)))

Can someone point me in right direction with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  bit more complex as you have first to unpivot Sheet2, then apply query, finally join the results in one cell.

```
=iferror(textjoin(char(10),,query(arrayformula(split(flatten(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4&"|"&Sheet2!$B$1:$F$1&"|"&Sheet2!$B$2:$F$4),"|")),"select Col2 where Col1='"&$A2&"' and Col3='"&B$1&"' ")))
```

adjust `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4&"|"&Sheet2!$B$1:$F$1&"|"&Sheet2!$B$2:$F$4`as necessary.

### Explanation

Sheet2 is like
[image]

To unpivot Sheet2, try

```
=arrayformula(split(flatten(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4&"|"&Sheet2!$B$1:$F$1&"|"&Sheet2!$B$2:$F$4),"|"))
```

[image]

then apply your query

```
query(_______________,"select Col2 where Col1='"&$A2&"' and Col3='"&B$1&"' ")
```

and finally join the results
[image]